# Implicit not found on store

Tags: phantom-dsl

I have followed the pattern from examples on GitHub. When I call store on the model object, passing an instance of the entity, I get a compile error indicating one of the implicit parameters is missing as shown below.

```
could not find implicit value for parameter sg: com.outworkers.phantom.macros.SingleGeneric.Aux[com.ss.wuhu.settlement.entity.Settlement,Repr,HL,Out]
```

I guess I am missing something obvious. Could someone please point out how to bring the implicit into scope?

Regards
Meeraj

This is the code snippet where I am storing the data.

```
import akka.Done
import com.outworkers.phantom.dsl._
import com.outworkers.phantom.connectors.{CassandraConnection, ContactPoints}
import com.ss.wuhu.settlement.entity.Settlement
import com.ss.wuhu.settlement.entity.mapping.{SettlementForCourierModel, SettlementForVendorModel}

object Connector {
    private val hosts = Seq("127.0.0.1") // TODO from environment
    lazy val connector: CassandraConnection = ContactPoints(hosts).keySpace("wuhu_order")
}

class SettlementDatabase(override val connector: CassandraConnection) extends Database[SettlementDatabase](connector) {

    object SettlementForCourierModel extends SettlementForCourierModel with connector.Connector
    object SettlementForVendorModel extends SettlementForVendorModel with connector.Connector

    def truncateAll() = {
        Database.truncate()
    }

    def store(set: Settlement) = {
        for {
            v <- Database.SettlementForVendorModel.store(set)
            d <- Database.SettlementForCourierModel.store(set)
        } yield (Done)
    }

}

object Database extends SettlementDatabase(Connector.connector)
```

Comment: I have tracked the error down, I had some type mismatch between the entity and model classes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug with an open issue: https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/issues/774

I suggest either using the workaround as described in the link above, or my workaround which was creating my own `.store()` using `.insert()`.

example:

```
def myStore(person: Person) : Future[ResultSet] =
 insert
   .value(_.name, person.name)
   .value(_.age, person.age)
   .value(_.timeCreate, person.timeCreate)
   .future()
```